# How can I override the default validations that come with Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have my own password/login rules that I want to implement such as:

- Password: At least one number, one lower case character and one upper case character
- Login: Alphanumeric and between 4 and 15 characters long

etc...

Currently when I do not enter a password and login in my form, I get the following errors (from Authlogic's default validations):

- Login is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
- Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters)
- Password confirmation is too short (minimum is 4 characters)

These validation rules are not in my model, they come from the Authlogic gem. I know there are configurations that I can add using:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.validate_password_field = false
end
```

The problem is that I can't find good documentation for these configurations and when I try the one above so I can use my own, it complains:
`undefined method 'password_confirmation' for #<User:0x7f5fac8fe7c0>`

Doing this:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.validate_password_field = false

  # added this so it might stop complaining
  config.require_password_confirmation = true
end
```

Does nothing.

Is there a way to have Authlogic require password confirmation while ignore all other validation so that I can control this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `undefined method 'password_confirmation'` can be avoided simply by adding this line in your model:

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation
```

If you want to handle the confirmation yourself, then just add:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

If you dive into the code, you will find this in `password.rb`:

```
if require_password_confirmation
  validates_confirmation_of :password, validates_confirmation_of_password_field_options
  validates_length_of :password_confirmation, validates_length_of_password_confirmation_field_options
end
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Also for anyone else's benefit, adding: `validate_login_field false` to the authlogic configuration will prevent login id validation as well.